# Azure DevOps pipeline build fails due to version conflict within Microsoft.AspNetCore packages

Tags: .net, azure-devops, botframework

I've been trying to set up a proper devops pipeline using Azure DevOps. My problem is very similar to other posts but none fixed my problem of:
`NU1607: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
     botProj (>= 1.0.0) -> Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.Typing (>= 1.0.82) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures (>= 2.1.1) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.1)
     botProj (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.0).)`

If I add this reference directly like suggested, then it just gives me a new one. I'd prefer to not have to add each one directly.

In this post:
[How do I resolve version conflicts in aspnet core 2.1? (2.1.1 >= 2.1.0-rc1-final)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031148/how-do-i-resolve-version-conflicts-in-aspnet-core-2-1-2-1-1-2-1-0-rc1-final?rq=1)

The Answer suggests that I just need to set `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` within my `.csproj` file.
I've done this but still get the same error.

In this post:
It is suggested to use a `dotnet-restore`, I believe I've put this into my `azure-pipelines.yml` but honestly it might be the wrong command so I will post my pipelines
[Azure DevOps build pipline constantly giving version conflict on every package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881453/azure-devops-build-pipline-constantly-giving-version-conflict-on-every-package#comment101314162_55881453)

Here is my `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
vmImage: 'windows-2019'

trigger:
- dev/mybranch

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '2.2.101'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'ibibot_ops/NuGet.Config'

- task: VSBuild@1
...
- task: VSTest@2
...
```

I'll post my `.csproj` in a gist:
https://gist.github.com/MilesWilde/e85f08f5bce40fa63222bbdcffc808cc

I also have a test `botProj.test.csproj` but it seems like it doesn't influence the errors so I won't post it unless it makes sense to.

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by specifying a version for the `NugetToolInstaller@0` task in my pipeline and using the `DotNetCoreInstaller@0`. This is my final .yml with some information removed

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.2.101'
  inputs:
    version: 2.2.101
  continueOnError: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.9.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.9.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.Config'

- task: VSBuild@1
...

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
...

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
...
```